# I don't have My Cart link anymore in the header

Tags: cart, theme

my header looks like this:
My Account     My Wishlist     Log In
Plus: I can't see my cart contents anymore on the right side bar after adding products.

I lately upgraded from 1.6 to 1.8.1 with hellowired.
That theme isn't compatible with 1.8.1 as it seems but I reckon with a few small changes it would work as well.

Does anybody know where to tweak what so that the Shopping Cart links show up?

Thanks

Comment: check if the link is there when you turn the base/default theme back on to make sure the issue is with your template. If it's just your template check the layout xml files where the cart is added or removed and add that code to your question to give us some more info

Comment: I merged the catalog.xml with the original one from the theme and commented the things out I didn't need and now it works again.
So it seems as if it came from the catalog and I simply commented out too much.

Comment: good to hear. Can you please post an answer with what you did to make it work and close the question?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, it seems as if the catalog.xml was the place to edit the links.
To ease it up, I used the themes' default catalog.xml and simply merged it with the the newest versions and didn't comment out anything.
And then - one by one I disabled the stuff I didn't need.
So I guess I just made a mistake somewhere in the first place and commented too much but wasn't able to figure out what exactly.